# Problema con ApiRestful con IONIC + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, angular, api, ionic

Estoy desarrollando un sistema que usa Ionic con Mysql, el problema recide en que soy incapaz de poder realizar un Post.

Estoy usando 000Webhost (gratuito).

Este es el código PHP.

```
<?php
    
 $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "X", "X", "X");
 
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 
 $CodPersona = $data->CodPersona;
 $Nombre = $data->Nombre;
 $ApePaterno = $data->ApePaterno;
 $ApeMaterno = $data->ApeMaterno;
 
 $consulta="INSERT into personas set CodPersona='$CodPersona', Nombre='$Nombre',ApePaterno='$ApePaterno',ApeMaterno='$ApeMaterno'";
 
 $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
 
 if ($result) 
 {
    http_response_code(201);
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'User created'));
 } 
    else 
 {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Internal Server error'));
 }

?>
```

Este es el código que realiza la petición en Ionic, siendo "userinfo" un objeto.

```
insertUsers(userinfo)
  {
    return this.http.post(`https://ceedb.000webhostapp.com/bd/insert.php`, userinfo);
  }
```

El error es que una vez hecho todo, no registra nada, pero cuando lo hago mediante postman, si registra.

Este es el error que sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Haz depuraciones con `var_dump` y dinos lo que muestra. Algo raro que veo es que usas `201` como supuesto código de respuesta exitosa, cuando generalmente se usa el código `200`. Tampoco es muy lógico dar arbitrariamente un código `500` cuando hay fallos. Un error en la lógica del código (por ejemplo un error a nivel de SQL de clave duplicada) no tiene por qué ser forzado a un error `500` que es un error interno del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un problema de cruce de dominios distintos. Revisa este articulo sobre [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Seguramente estas haciendo la peticion http desde otro dominio (local o de un dominio distinto a ceedb.000webhostapp.com, por lo que la peticion entrega un error.

EL navegador esta intentando obtener mediante OPTIONS las opciones que tiene para obtener el recurso. Espera encontrar algunos encabezados como:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dominio.origen
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
```

Por lo que podrias agregar a tu script PHP algunos encabezados:

```
<?php
// permitir peticiones a este script desde cierto origen (puede usar * para probar inicialmente)
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://tu.dominio.origen"); 
// Que tipos de metodos son posibles
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```

Si dichos encabezados no son suficientes, revisa el articulo que te indicara otras opciones o requisitos para que la peticion sea realizada con exito.